# how to extend interface/class on variable declaration

Tags: typescript

How do I extend an interface or class on variable declaration?

For example:

```
export declare abstract class DynamicFormControlModel implements DynamicPathable {
    asyncValidators: DynamicValidatorsConfig | null;
    _disabled: boolean;
    disabledUpdates: Subject<boolean>;
    errorMessages: DynamicValidatorsConfig | null;
    hidden: boolean;
    id: string;
    label: string | null;
    labelTooltip: string | null;
    controlTooltip: string | null;
    layout: DynamicFormControlLayout | null;
    name: string;
    parent: DynamicPathable | null;
    relation: DynamicFormControlRelationGroup[];
    updateOn: FormHooks | null;
    validators: DynamicValidatorsConfig | null;
    abstract readonly type: string;
    protected constructor(config: DynamicFormControlModelConfig, layout?: DynamicFormControlLayout | null);
    disabled: boolean;
    readonly hasErrorMessages: boolean;
    toJSON(): Object;
}

model: DynamicFormControlModel extend {value:string}
```

- `model: DynamicFormControlModel extend {value:string}` returns error
- I know I could `extend {value: string}` or include "value" on the class itself, but I'm not looking for this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
let model: DynamicFormControlModel & {value:string};
```

Comment: Hi @MattMcCutchen, thanks for your answer. i'd been searching for an hour and your answer solve my issue.